# How to run an AWS EMR cluster on multiple subnets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

Currently we are creating instances using a config.json file from EMR to configure the cluster. This file specifies a subnet ("Ec2SubnetId").

*ALL* of my EMR instances end up using this subnet...how do I let it use multiple subnets?
Here is the terraform template I am pushing to S3.

```
{
   "Applications": [
        {"Name": "Spark"},
        {"Name": "Hadoop"}
    ],
    "BootstrapActions": [
        {
            "Name": "Step1-stuff",
            "ScriptBootstrapAction": {
                "Path": "s3://${artifact_s3_bucket_name}/artifacts/${build_commit_id}/install-stuff.sh",
                "Args": ["${stuff_args}"]
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "setup-cloudWatch-agent",
            "ScriptBootstrapAction": {
                "Path": "s3://${artifact_s3_bucket_name}/artifacts/${build_commit_id}/setup-cwagent-emr.sh",
                "Args": ["${build_commit_id}"]
            }
        }
    ],
    "Configurations": [
        {
            "Classification": "spark",
            "Properties": {
                "maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"
            }
    ],
    "Instances": {
        "AdditionalMasterSecurityGroups": [ "${additional_master_security_group}" ],
        "AdditionalSlaveSecurityGroups": [ "${additional_slave_security_group}" ],
        "Ec2KeyName": "privatekey-${env}",
        "Ec2SubnetId": "${data_subnet}",
        "InstanceGroups": [
```

Comment: It looks like i may have to use an "Instance Fleet" to do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot currently achieve what you are trying to do. EMR clusters always end up with all of their nodes in the same subnet.

Using Instance Fleets, you are indeed able to configure a set of subnets.. but at *launch* time, AWS will choose the best *one* and put all your instances there.

From the [EMR Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-instance-fleet.html), under "Use the Console to Configure Instance Fleets":

> 5. For **Network**, enter a value. If you choose a VPC for **Network**, choose a single **EC2 Subnet** or CTRL + click to choose multiple EC2 subnets. The subnets you select must be the same type (public or private). If you choose only one, your cluster launches in that subnet. **If you choose a group, the subnet with the best fit is selected from the group when the cluster launches.**